Simple html-Card Game needs the url of a wix media folder. Is there another easy way, without api and all that stuff?
First of all: Sorry for my maybe stupid Question, but I'm a complete beginner in programming.
With great difficulty and the help of AI I wrote an html with Java(?) that runs perfect locally in my browser. The aim is to randomly reveal one of 136 fate cards, after pressing a button.
Now I want to add this game to my Wix homepage, but how?
I have no idea how Wix names the address of this folder (folder is called Schicksalskarten) in the Media folder that contains all of these images. I found out the url of a single image, but not the url of the folder. I also tried to get the images from the Google Drive folder, at least it has an address, but that requires some kind of API and that became too complicated for me and now I'm totally confused, I've tried so many things. Is there any way to make this easy? As far as I'm concerned, the images folder doesn't have to be in Wix, it can be anywhere, these images don't need to be protected or anything like that... The cards have the nrs 1-136. Here's the code that works at home...
SCHICKSALSKARTEN
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Fraktur", serif;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #D4AF37;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
}

#image {
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
}

button {
  font-family: "Fraktur", serif;
  background-color: #D4AF37;
  color: #000000;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #C09F2F;
}



<h1>SCHICKSALSKARTEN</h1>

<h3>Drücke auf "Karte ziehen", um Dein Schicksal zu erfahren!</h3>

<br>
<button onclick="drawRandomCard()">Karte ziehen</button>
<br> <br>

<img src="ruecken.jpg" id="image">


// Array zum Speichern der Bilder
var images = [];

// Alle Bilder im Ordner durchlaufen
for (var i = 1; i <= 134; i++) {
  // Bildpfad erstellen
  var imagePath = i + ".jpg";
  
  // Bild in das Array hinzufügen
  images.push(imagePath);
}

// Funktion zum Ziehen einer zufälligen Karte
function drawRandomCard() {
  // Zufälliges Bild auswählen
  var randomImage = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  
  // Bild laden
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    // Startbild durch gezogene Karte ersetzen
    var imageElement = document.getElementById("image");
    imageElement.src = image.src;
  };
  image.src = randomImage;
}

I've tried to put an url into var images [here], I've tried to put all the images in a google drive folder, etc... Gemini and Bard could not solve my problem. But it's only, because I'm a compeletely beginner...
